# How to overcome type mismatch error using the Join function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm stuck trying to solve the [Run-time error '13': Type mismatch] error on the Join function.  Can anyone maybe give me some direction as to how to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub subWriteListObject(shtXer As Worksheet, strListObjectName As String, fileFileOut As Integer)

Dim varRangeArray As Variant
Dim varRowArray As Variant
Dim lRowIterate As Long
Dim strStringWrite As String

Print #fileFileOut, "%T" & vbTab & strListObjectName

varRangeArray = shtXer.ListObjects(strListObjectName).Range.Value

For lRowIterate = 1 To UBound(varRangeArray)
    varRowArray = Application.Index(varRangeArray, lRowIterate, 0)
    strStringWrite = Join(varRowArray, vbTab)
    Print #fileFileOut, strStringWrite
Next

Set varRangeArray = Nothing
Set varRowArray = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have added a watch for varRowArray.  It seems to be a 1 dimensional array of strings.

I have tried ", " as a delimiter, with no better results.

I'm absolutely stumped.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Frustration - I did not see there was a variant error 2029 in one of the array elements (just out of screen on the initial look at the watch table).

So, solution - make sure that each element in the array is of proper type in itself.  If any element is in error, Join will fail on it I assume.

Comment: More specifically, it needs to be able to be coerced into a `String`.